# Alternatives for reopening buffers from last session in VIM?

Tags: vim, usability

I know `:mksession`, and I use it, but sometimes, it's too much, it saves too much state, which is a problem, for example, when you update some plugins, and want to close/open VIM to start it in a fresh state, except you want to preserve the state for the current opened files, solely.

Sometimes what `:mksession` saves conflicts with the new updated configuration, prevents from loading parts of it, etc.

So, what are good alternatives (maybe including plugins) for reopening VIM and loading last buffer list, without that much extra state from `:mksession`?

Comment: What an awesome command!

Comment: @Marenz check the plugins [obsession.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-obsession) or [vim-session](https://github.com/xolox/vim-session), you'll appreciate this command even more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess I figured what I wanted out going through `:h :mksession`:

```
set sessionoptions=blank,buffers,curdir,help,tabpages,winsize
```

Now `mksession` saves much less state than the default for `sessionoptions`:

`'sessionoptions' 'ssop'`:

- default: blank,buffers,curdir,folds,help,options,tabpages,winsize