# VIM keybinding to jump back to initial position after indenting the whole file

Tags: vim, indentation, key-bindings

I have created a keybinding that should indent a whole file.
My first solution looked like this:

```
map <F4> gg=G
```

The problem is that after pressing F4, the cursor jumped to the first line of the file. So I have tried to improve my solution with the feature of markers, look like this:

```
map <F4> mzgg=G'z<CR>
```

I expected this would have resolved my problem, but the command do the same as the first. When I try to jump to the z marker manually vim told me "marker not set".

After changing the keybinding, I have or course restarted vim! I am using the GVIM 7.3 on a WIN 7 machine.

Thank you in advance for your Help!

Edit:

After trying to get my keybinding working by tipping it directly to vim commandline. I find out that the keybinding was working quite nice. I think problem is that I create a session some times ago (with mksession) and if you load a session I think vim ignores the vimrc-file. Is this assumption right?

Solution:

In these [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670786/alternatives-for-reopening-buffers-from-last-session-in-vim)  I find a soultion to make mksession save less options.

Comment: if 'sessionoptions' contains 'options' it saves global mapping, so I assume that even you modified your .vimrc, the old mapping that was stored in the session overrides your modification at startup. So yes, you better try on a new session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend the use of <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> which allow to go respectively backward and forward in the jump list. See `:help jumps`.

The following mapping

```
map <F4> gg=G2<C-o>
```

works. (It jumps back two times in the jump list)

But generally, the jump list is a great way to navigate in a file, this is likely the shortcuts that use the most in my daily use. It is also works if you jump to a tag to go back to your original location.

You might also want to use `nnoremap` rather than `map`, this way it will only work in normal mode, and you could potentially reuse <kbd>F4</kbd> in combination in another key binding without having recursive mappings.

so

```
nnoremap <F4> gg=G2<C-o>
```

Comment: Cool, I think the jump forward and backward shortcuts can help my to improve my productivity speed much.

Comment: I would do `map <F4> Hgg=G2<C-o>zt<C-o>`, as that will also move the original top line back to the top so the buffer doesn't move at all.

Comment: @GaryFixler: that'a a nice enhancement!

Comment: Thanks. I have similar ones for my `g*` and `g#` maps, which are just non-moving versions of `*` and `#`.

Answer (score 4):

Another lightweight approach: set the ` mark, format the buffer and jump back to the mark afterwards.

```
:nnoremap <key> m`gg=G``
```

Comment: Has the ' mark any special behavior or work it like the z marker I use?

Comment: @P.Schreiber, mark ` is automatically set to the current cursor location every time you use a jump command (`:help jump-motions`).